# Use REGEX to swap order of terms around a comma where the terms have a certain class

Tags: xml, regex

hopeless at this sort of stuff so grateful for any help.

I have a list of c80000 terms in format like this:

```
<term>
    <termId>100323N166777388LGH3cj24jYcDY75lTgZl</termId>
    <termName>term1</termName>
    <termType>UNUSE</termType>
       <relation>
      <relationType>USE</relationType>
      <termId>OMITERMO6650</termId>
      <termName>term3, term4</termName>
    </relation>
  </term>
  <term>
    <termId>OMITERMO6650</termId>
      <termName>term3, term4</termName>
    <termType>Pt</termType>
     </term>
```

is it possible to write a regex (or else any other find and replace in notepad++) to swap the order of terms around if there is a comma in a tag which has `<termType>Pt</termType>` and is referenced in `<relation>` attributes.  So in the example, term 3 and 4 would be swapped.

Not all PT terms are referenced in `<relation>`, but where they are they'd need to be swapped too.  Also, not all terms have a comma seperating values in them, so they should be ignored

Hopefully this makes sense, many thanks!

Comment: Usually using regex to manipulate XML is just inviting a big headache, especially with the enormous amount of support for actual XML parsing out there.  I'd advise against using a regex solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<termName>term3, term4</termName>" | sed -E 's/<termName>(.*), (.*)<\/termName>/<tN>\2, \1<\/tn>/' 
<tn>term4, term3</tn>
```

Of course I just used 'tn' as abbreviation. Regex in Notepad++ might differ - maybe you have to mask the parentheses with backslash. It swaps inside termName everywhere - I hope I understood this right.

It will not be sensitive to comments, and it will not match tags, spanning over multiple rows. But of course, it is easy to test your file beforewards (grep for all 'termnames') for the second case, and comments might not be a problem.